# Differentiating the following average.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to find $\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial r^2} \frac{1}{|\partial B(x,r)|} \int_{\partial B(x,r)} u(y,t)\mathrm{d}y $ . Where $B$ is a ball of radius $r$ with center at $x$ .

Differentiating once was ok , but i couldn't not again differentiate .

Thank you for your help .

Comment: What's "average" doing in there?

Comment: @joriki : I don't know how to make it $\int$ with the cut , ie average of  surface integral .

Comment: AFAIK the `\strokedint` or `\fint` commands are not implemented in MathJax, so I just replaced it by the definition.

Comment: @WillieWong : Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the first section of chapter 5 of the classical book by [Fritz John Partial Differential equations](http://books.google.es/books?id=cBib_bsGGLYC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=Fritz%20John%20Partial%20Differential%20equations&source=bl&ots=axn6v-wevW&sig=DAkp7ry65t_cEdeJilBDK5k2bCM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zwz8T7jhHZTB0gX2mOW-Dg&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=Fritz%20John%20Partial%20Differential%20equations&f=false) (and in many other books on PDE's).